# Estimation of operator norm of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, estimation

Let $A$ be an $n*n$ real-symetric matrix, B be a $p*n$ real matrix and $\eta$ be a real number. I want to know if we can give an upper bound of the following inverse matrix
$G={\begin{pmatrix}
A-i\eta I_n & B^T\\
B & -I_p
\end{pmatrix}}^{-1}$.

It's easy to see that if $p=0$, then $||G||\leq \eta^{-1}$. But when $p$ is not $0$, how can I give an upper bound of the norm? Does anybody have any ideas or references about this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you want an upper bound for the **norm of** $G$?

Comment: A possibly useful result from Bhatia's Matrix analysis: Let $A$ be Hermitian, and $B$ skew-Hermitian.  Let their eigenvalues be arranged so that
$$
|\alpha_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\alpha_n| \quad \text{and} \quad |\beta_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\beta_n|
$$
Then
$$
\|A - B\| \geq \max_{j}|\alpha_j - \beta_{n-j+1}| = \max_{j} \sqrt{|\alpha_j|^2 + |\beta_{n - j+1}|^2}
$$

Comment: Actually, the following is probably more useful: let $A$ be Hermitian, and $B$ skew-Hermitian.  Let their eigenvalues be arranged so that
$$
|\alpha_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\alpha_n| \quad \text{and} \quad |\beta_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\beta_n|
$$
Let $T = A + B$, and let $s_j$ be the singular values of $T$.  Then the following majorization relations are satisfied:
$$
\{|\alpha_j + \beta_{n - j+1}|^2\}_j \prec \{s_j^2\}_j\\
\left\{\frac 12(s_j^2 + s_{n - j + 1}^2) \right\}_j \prec \{|\alpha_j + \beta_{j}|^2\}_j
$$

Comment: Notably, the norm of your matrix $G = M^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of the smallest singular value of $M$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Thanks a lot for your help! And I find that if we take $n=p=1$ and $B=b, A=-b^2$, then $||G|| \to +\infty$ as $b \to +\infty$. So maybe the estimate does not exist.

Comment: You might have interesting upper bounds for $\|G\|\cdot \|M\|$ (where $G = M^{-1}$) though